# Converting rows into more columns

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, string-function

i have a table with 4 columns `ID`,`ROL_NUM`,`NAME`,`DEPT` and having records as below :

```
ID          ROL_NUM     NAME        DEPT
1           1           Rajasekar   CSE
1           1           Bala        CSE
1           1           Poo         IT
1           1           bhasker     CSE
```

I need output from this table as follows

```
ID          ROL_NUM             NAME                DEPT            NAME            DEPT            NAME            DEPT            NAME            DEPT
1           1                   Rajasekar           CSE             Bala            CSE             Poo             It              bhasker         CSE
```

Someone provide a sugesstion or help me by providing the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Aggregation for such a pivoting :

```
select ID, rol_num, max( case when rn = 1 then name end ) as name1,
                    max( case when rn = 1 then dept end ) as dept1,
                    max( case when rn = 2 then name end ) as name2,
                    max( case when rn = 2 then dept end ) as dept2,
                    max( case when rn = 3 then name end ) as name3,
                    max( case when rn = 3 then dept end ) as dept3,
                    max( case when rn = 4 then name end ) as name4,
                    max( case when rn = 4 then dept end ) as dept4                    
  from
  (
  select t.*, row_number() over (order by t.name) as rn
    from tab t
   order by t.name 
  )
  group by ID, rol_num
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d988c2c5a3de86a15c726ed82614905c)</kbd>

Comment: What about 100 rows?

Comment: what about your solution alternative @AnkitBajpai ?

Comment: I was trying to do this using pivot with maximum 10 cols but just stucked with double column pivoting.

Comment: you can do dynamic pivoting in SQL Server, but there's no such direct way within Oracle's SQL @AnkitBajpai

Comment: Hmmm Correct. Even I also think now that this is one of the best possible ways to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
ID,
ROL_NUM,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 1) NAME,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 2) DEPT,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 3) NAME,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 4) DEPT,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 5) NAME,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 6) DEPT,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 7) NAME,
REGEXP_SUBSTR(NAMEDEPT, '[^,]+', 1, 8) DEPT
from (SELECT ID
      ,ROL_NUM
      ,LISTAGG(NAME || ',' ||DEPT,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ID) AS NAMEDEPT
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID,ROL_NUM);
```

**Output**

```
ID  ROL_NUM NAME    DEPT    NAME    DEPT    NAME        DEPT    NAME    DEPT
1   1       Bala    CSE     Poo     IT      Rajasekar   CSE     bhasker CSE
```

**DEMO:**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/beb53/19

Answer (score 0):

Following query may help you.

```
select
   id,
         rol_num,
   substr(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(name, ','),2) name_list
from
   (
   select
     id,
         rol_num,
     name,
     count(*) OVER ( partition by id) cnt,
     ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( partition by id order by name) seq
   from test where id is not null)
where
   seq=cnt
start with
   seq=1
connect by prior
   seq+1=seq
and prior id=id;
```

Output

```
ID    ROL_NUM      NAME_LIST
1        1         Bala,Rajasekar
```

Similarly, you can add dept_list.

Comment: This is surely not the expected answer.

Comment: Showing all the rows in columns for Name and Dept will not be feasible solution as there can be thousands of rows. So showing name in comma separated list in single column can be helpful and then they can be segregated if required.

Comment: But this is not the requirement from OP.

Comment: I gave alternative solution as i couldn't find any way of doing this in oracle.